# Unable to create buckets in Hive in cloudera

Tags: hive, bigdata, cloudera, bucket

I am trying to create a bucketed table in Hive in Cloudera. But, a normal table is created without any buckets.

First, I have created a normal table using  named marks_temp using Hive CLI

```
CREATE  TABLE marks_temp(
id INT,
Name string,
mark int
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

I have loaded following data into marks_temp table from a text file which is 'Desktop/Data/littlebigdata.txt'

```
101,Firdaus,88
102,Pranav,78
103,Rahul,65
104,Sanjoy,65
105,Firdaus,88
106,Pranav,78
107,Rahul,65
108,Sanjoy,65
109,Amar,54
110,Sahil,34
111,Rahul,45
112,Rajnish,67
113,Ranjeet,56
114,Sanjoy,34
```

I have loaded above data using below command

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'Desktop/Data/littlebigdata.txt'
INTO TABLE  marks_temp;
```

After successful data loading, I am creating a bucketed table named as marks_temp

```
CREATE TABLE marks_bucketed(
id INT,
Name string,
mark int
)
CLUSTERED BY (id) INTO 4 BUCKETS;
```

Now, I am inserting data in marks_bucketed table  from marks_temp table.

```
INSERT INTO marks_bucketed
SELECT id,Name, mark FROM marks_temp;
```

After this some jobs start to run. What, I have observed in the job logs that it is saying "Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator"

```
hive> insert into marks_bucketed
        > select id,Name,mark from marks_temp;
    Query ID = cloudera_20180601035353_29b25ffe-541e-491e-aea6-b36ede88ed79
    Total jobs = 3
    Launching Job 1 out of 3
    Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
    Starting Job = job_1527668582032_0004, Tracking URL = http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1527668582032_0004/
    Kill Command = /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1527668582032_0004
    Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 0
    2018-06-01 03:54:01,328 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
    2018-06-01 03:54:14,444 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 2.21 sec
    MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 2 seconds 210 msec
    Ended Job = job_1527668582032_0004
    Stage-4 is selected by condition resolver.
    Stage-3 is filtered out by condition resolver.
    Stage-5 is filtered out by condition resolver.
    Moving data to: hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/marks_bucketed/.hive-staging_hive_2018-06-01_03-53-45_726_2788383119636056364-1/-ext-10000
    Loading data to table default.marks_bucketed
    Table default.marks_bucketed stats: [numFiles=1, numRows=14, totalSize=194, rawDataSize=180]
    MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
    Stage-Stage-1: Map: 1   Cumulative CPU: 2.21 sec   HDFS Read: 3937 HDFS Write: 273 SUCCESS
    Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 2 seconds 210 msec
    OK
    Time taken: 31.307 seconds
```

Even, Hue File Browser is showing only one file. Screenshot is attached.
[Hue File Browser screenshot for marks_bucketed table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dW8SP.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Hive documentation

> Version 0.x and 1.x only
>
> The command set hive.enforce.bucketing = true; allows the correct
>   number of reducers and the cluster by column to be automatically
>   selected based on the table. Otherwise, you would need to set the
>   number of reducers to be the same as the number of buckets as in set
>   mapred.reduce.tasks = 256; and have a CLUSTER BY ... clause in the
>   select.

so you will need to set the property to force the bucketing or go for the manual option and run your query like

```
set mapred.reduce.tasks = 4;
select id,Name,mark from marks_temp cluster by id;
```